# How to check the file creation date basing on the URL?

Tags: c#, java, php

I have an URL to a XML file, is there any posibility to get its creation date ?

Comment: Unfortuneantly no, you can't.

Comment: This is a piece of metadata not available via HTTP through any standard mechanism. There's also a good chance, since it's XML, that it's dynamically generated on each request, and therefore the traditional concept of the "creation date" would not apply to it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO.
because its a web url you possibly cannot get more information that what the web server exposes

Answer (score 3):

Yes can get a file information using `CURL`  [curl_getinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) without having to return the entire body

Example

```
$curl = curl_init('URL_TO_XML');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if ($result === false) {
    die (curl_error($curl)); 
}
$timestamp = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_FILETIME);
if ($timestamp != -1) { 
    echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
}
```

Comment: This worked nicely, it returned the file date and time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it that way

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(url);

// Creates an HttpWebRequest for the specified URL. 
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri); 
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
// Uses the LastModified property to compare with today's date.
if (DateTime.Compare(today,myHttpWebResponse.LastModified) == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("\nThe requested URI entity was modified today");
else
    if (DateTime.Compare(today,myHttpWebResponse.LastModified) == 1)
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe requested URI was last modified on:{0}",
                        myHttpWebResponse.LastModified);
    // Releases the resources of the response.

myHttpWebResponse.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
you can if you have access to that file then you can use urllib2.

For python2.7 try this:

```
req = urllib2.build_opener()

req.addheaders = [('User-Agent')]

#for full detail use this: 
    meta = req.open(link).info()

meta =req.open(link).info().getheader("Last-Modified")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).